# Excel: Ensure Page Break View setup in Excel stays with document shared/ sent to someone else?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, printing, preview

By default apparently the Page Break configuration that I setup inside an Excel file does not go to another person on their machine.

I wanted them to print it that way. They could change it but they wanted to have my "page break setup" for their printing.

Anyway to make this go through or stay with Excel? It would be hard to show/ ask the other person in any other way without a crazy long Screen sharing session.

Answer (score 1):

Office application's page layout, including page breaks, are affected by the printer selected as default on the computer the file is being viewed on.

This results in your page breaks (and other things) changing when the file is opened on another computer that has a different printer attached.

In this case, the only way I can think to keep the page layout would be to save the spreadsheet as a PDF before sending it.

Sorry. I don't have any reference for this other than experience.